# The type 'class' in 'directory\class.aspx.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'class' in 'app'. Using type defined in 'directory\class.aspx.cs'

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms, devexpress

I've been fighting with this issue all day. VS2019, these warnings started coming up after switching the application to use Windows Authentication. No matter what markup I focus on, I receive this error on each and every one. This is a solution containing one project.

Some things I have tried:

1. Clean, rebuild, restart.
2. Checked references to see if there was any cyclical references, none.
3. No 'App_Code' folder used.
4. Cleaned up registry items regarding VS2019.
5. Delete bin and obj.
6. Deleted all references, re added each.
7. Cleared nuget cache.
8. Made sure that 'class' wasn't duplicated anywhere.
9. Fully qualified namespace in .cs and .aspx.
10. Delete temporary aspx files.

Just hoping someone else has some suggestions. My last option would be to create the project from scratch. I understand these warnings aren't breaking, however they lead me to believe there is something wrong behind the scenes.

Comment: Any way to re-name that page? Using a "page" name the same as reserved words, say DataTable.aspx creates a page called DataTable, and that conflicts with the bult in type of "DataTable". So now, both the page class, and the type of DataTable have the same name. This also suggests that at one time this was a asp.net web site, and now it a asp.net web site application.  I guess I am saying that naming a page the same as a base type object is a bad idea, and if possible re-name the page to say MyClass,or something else.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal One example page name is 'PropertyDetailList'. I felt that this was specific enough that it would not cause such a condition. And to answer your second question, this is an ASP.NET WebForms Web Application. This has never changed and so I'm slightly confused by what you mean by this.

Comment: I would also like to mention that this happens on all markups, regardless of the name. The name provided above is an example of a markup name that is providing the warning.

Comment: Well, we all fishing for answers here. So my comment was just a FYI. I have found that if I name a web page the same as an existing object, it can cause issues in code. As you note/suggest/hint you not changed anything, but then again, something must have been changed here? We don't have your project in front of us, so attempting to debug in a dark room with a blindfold on is a challenge for the public here. However, the hint/context/suggest was in regards to if this was a "asp.net website" vs a asp.net web site application". And your errors often crop up when trying to run a web site as app.

Comment: @AlbertD.Kallal Completely understandable. This is an ASP.NET Web application that is being run on IIS. The only thing that I changed prior to this occurring was added a Windows authentication method to the web.config and set up a corresponding sitemap with those permissions. It just baffles me how changing something so insignificant could cause these warnings to appear. They aren't associated to eachother in any way other than the sitemap must access the roles provided in the AD Windows authentication, which I've already tested as working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use the word "**class**" as your Class name. It's the reserved keyword for C#